# Lost SQL credentials and unable to connect to SQL via SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, connectivity, logins, sqlcmd

I have a machine running SQL 2014 but have neither the windows authentication or `sa` authentication details due to mismanagement of a previous support team.

Having tried logging in to SQL Management Studio using my Microsoft AD account I received the following error:

> ===Cannot connect to BACKUP-MGMT-01\CONSULT.===
>   A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I suspect this is due to my account not having privileges.

I then found some steps online allowing you to add a new `sa` or windows authenticated user via SQLCMD. However, when I run either the `SQLCMD -S .\BACKUP-MGMT-01\CONSULT` or `SQLCMD -S .\BACKUP-MGMT-01` I just receive the following error:

> C:\Users\frank>SQLCMD -S .\BACKUP-MGMT-01\CONSULT
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Inte
>   rfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]. .
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>   Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : A network-related or in
>   stance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
>   . Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and i
>   f SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see
>    SQL Server Books Online..

Can anybody assist?

Comment: Do you have access to an admin account of windows (member of the Administrators group) on the server? If yes, you could try [Start SQL Server in Single-User Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Hi Ronaldo, thank you for the info. Does this mean I can login to the management studio without any credentials and create a new sa account?

Comment: Yes Fraz it's exactly that, but it will only work if the Remote DAC setting is turned on

Comment: Yes. You can follow the instructions of the [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-ver15) documentation.

Comment: Hi Ronaldo, thanks for your help with this. The instructions in the link worked and I was able to login and add a new user for Windows authentication .

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format of the parameter `-S` for the `SQLCMD` prompt is: `Server\Instance`.

You seem to have tried `localhost\instance\database` which doesn't work.

```
SQLCMD -S .\BACKUP-MGMT-01\CONSULT 
          ^^        ^     ^   ^
          ||        |     |   +--- Database 
          ||        |     +------- Separator
          ||        +------------- Instance
          |+---------------------- Separator
          +----------------------- Server (. = localhost)
```

In any case the error message is stating you are having issues with the server name and/or instance name.

If your server is named `BACKUP-MGMT-01` and your instance is named `CONSULT` then you might want to try:

```
SQLCMD -S BACKUP-MGMT-01\CONSULT -E
```

If your instance is really named `BACKUP-MGMT-01` then you might want to try:

```
SQLCMD -S .\BACKUP-MGMT-01 -E -d CONSULT
```

Where `-d` is the parameter for database and `-E` is for trusted connections.

#### Reference Reading

[sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) (Microsoft | Docs | SQL Docs)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the detailed information - much appreciated. BTW, the windows server is called "BACKUP-MGMT-01" and the database instance is called "CONSULT". So i going by your comments above i should have tried:   

SQLCMD -S BACKUP-MGMT-01\CONSULT -E